# Webpack: How do I bundle all files from ./dist directory, like .js and .html, into a single .js output file?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, config, bundle

I have populated `./dist` directory with such files, after building them using some configs in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
commons_and_vendors.86aaeee0ed97868fdf96.js
egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.8496fa01a4fbe1e75728.js
egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.html
egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.ae1339b530352ebd88ef.js
egm_mm_wrapper_overhead_display.html
ilink_media_scheduler.3c3ca5b0d86635d724e9.js
ilink_media_scheduler.html
ilink_window_manager.1422201e2cf99eede513.js
ilink_window_manager.html
```

Every `.html` file import script corresponding to the name.

So `egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.html` import script .e.g. : `<script defer="defer" src="/egm_mm_wrapper_bottom_banner.8496fa01a4fbe1e75728.js">`

What I'd like to achieve, is to bundle all of the files into single `.js` file.

So .e.g. `bundle.js` would need to import every html and corresponding to htmls scripts and the rest of scripts not loaded inside htmls.

What if I'd import html manually, like that: `import html from "./file.html";`, what would I need to do with that imported variable, to make the contents of html file be injected into bundled js file as a string, that will be loaded later while using the bundled file?

The [html-loader package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader) for webpack seems easy to use when looking at the docs, but when it comes to practice I don't know what I'm doing, honestly.